Do Shadow Monks count as spell casters?
Shadow Arts gives you some spells you can cast with Ki, but not the spellcaster class feature or spell slots. However it does give you Minor Illusion as a cantrip, and I believe that races who get cantrip count as spellcasters, even if they don't have a leveled spell or slot (i.e. High Elves). I figured that thanks to Minor Illusion, it allows Shadow Monks to count as spell casters, especially for magic items that require attunement from Spellcasters.
